# How can I filter data in spss by multiple conditions

Tags: filter, spss

I am working with a large dataset on SPSS. I have certain inclusion and exclusion criteria for a research project, but I am unsure how to filter the data by complex conditions.

For example, I want to include cases that satisfy specific criteria:

Inclusion:
Had surgery, cancer was in the oropharynx, cancer was in the oral cavity

Exclude:
has metastatic disease, no biopsy done, has missing data on survival and margin status.

The variables given to me are complicated. For example the variable for the primary site of cancer is a list of strings  which describe different parts on the body. I would have to recode this into being oropharynx or oral cavity and then I only want cases with either of those sites.

What is the best systematic approach using syntax? Should I use Do IF, IF ELSE statements? or filter by?

Im not sure how to filter by all of these conditions in the syntax editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to calculate a new variable with all the conditions, then use it to filter.

In the following example, variable `filt` will receive value 1 for cases that have all the conditions, and 0 for those that don't:

```
compute filt=
   (varA="this" or varA="that") and
   not missing(varB) and
   (varC>=10 and varC<=20).

filter by filt.
```

If you don't need the other cases later, instead of `filter` you can use:

```
select if filt=1.
```

Comment: It is starting to make sense but I hit a road block. 
```compute filt  =  not missing (HISTOLOGY) and
      Range(HISTOLOGY, 8050,8084) /*select SCC histology 
      and (PRIMARY_SITE = "C000" or PRIMARY_SITE= "C001" ). /* filter for oral cavity and oropharynx 
      
filter by filt.
select if filt = 1.

FREQUENCIES PRIMARY_SITE```I tried this syntax but I cannot filter for both primary site c000 and c002. It only returns c000 when I check the frequency

Comment: Your `compute` says `PRIMARY_SITE= "C001"` and you say you are looking for "C002" in your frequencies - could that be the reason? Also, are you sure there are cases that are `PRIMARY_SITE= "C002"` and also have all the other conditions?. BTW you don't need both `filter` and `select` - it's either or.

Comment: The issue was the double quotes. for some reason it wanted me to write them in single quotes. I think I had a bunch of quote errors all around. I rewrote it and it worked